# Getting error 503 after adding listener class in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, jetty, listener, web.xml

I am using **Jetty** server and I want to put one check at the time of server start.
For that I have created one listener class and put its entry in web.xml as per following:

**Listener Class:**

```
public class LicenseCheck extends ContextLoaderListener
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LicenseCheck.class);

    public LicenseCheck()
    {
        log.info("Checking license");
    }
}
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


  <!-- spring context listener -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>com.license.LicenseCheck</listener-class>
    </listener>


   <!-- Index pages -->
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

But after adding this, my application cannot start and its throwing following exception:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
>       Service Unavailable
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty://

If I remove the listener's entry from web.xml it works fine.

Please provide solution for this.

Comment: Jetty has logs. They will probably make it clear what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solutions from log:

Log says:

> 2014-04-03 18:50:41.969:WARN::Failed startup of context
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@58afc4dd{/SpringMVCRest,D:\Workspace\SpringMVCRest\WebContent}
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because
>   there is already a root application context present - check whether
>   you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:265)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97) 2014-04-03
>   18:50:42.047:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080

So I found 2 solutions:

1. Remove the inheritance of ContextLoaderListener in my class.
2. Keep the inheritance and remove  entry of ContextLoaderListener from web.xml

Both worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Listeners are called in the order you specify it in web.xml.

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.license.LicenseCheck</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    public class LicenseCheck  implements   ServletContextListener {
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {      
        /* This method is called when the servlet context is         
            initialized(web app is deployed/started).          
            You can initialize servlet context related data here.      
        */     
        //Write your logic to check license expiry  
        }    

        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {      
            /* This method is invoked when the servlet context ( web app) is undeployed or server shuts down.      
            */                  
            //Do nothing
        }   
    }
```

This way LicenseCheck will execute first and check expiry even before applicationContext is loaded by ContextLoaderListener.